# draw a donut in d3js from json data

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to draw a donut from `secondOrderList` data with d3js. But I'm getting an error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at SVGGElement.pie (pie.js:16)
What am I doing wrong?

```
export default class SecondOrder extends Component {
componentDidUpdate(){
    var width = 1000;
    var height = 500;
    var fullAngle = 2 * Math.PI;
    var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - 10;

    var svgContainer = select(".container")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .style("border", "1px solid");

    var secondOrderList = [0:{name: "1.5", firstOrderWeight: 1, secondOrderWeight: 26, secondOrderTargets: Array(21), secondOrderImpact: 14}
                           1:{name: "2.4", firstOrderWeight: 1, secondOrderWeight: 23, secondOrderTargets: Array(14), secondOrderImpact: 12.5}
                           2:{name: "6.5", firstOrderWeight: 2, secondOrderWeight: 22, secondOrderTargets: Array(17), secondOrderImpact: 24}
                           3:{name: "7.2", firstOrderWeight: -1, secondOrderWeight: 12, secondOrderTargets: Array(18), secondOrderImpact: -7}
                           4:{name: "13.1", firstOrderWeight: 2, secondOrderWeight: 28, secondOrderTargets: Array(22), secondOrderImpact: 30}
                           5:{name: "15.2", firstOrderWeight: 2, secondOrderWeight: 12, secondOrderTargets: Array(10), secondOrderImpact: 14}
                           6:{name: "15.5", firstOrderWeight: 2, secondOrderWeight: 16, secondOrderTargets: Array(10), secondOrderImpact: 18}]


    var group = svgContainer.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 200 + "," + 250 + ")")

    var one_arc = arc()
        .outerRadius(100)
        .innerRadius(50);

    var pies = pie().value(d => {Math.abs(d.secondOrderImpact)});

    group.selectAll(".seconOrderDonut")
        .data(pies)
        .enter()
            .append('g')
        .classed("seconOrderDonut", true)

    group.append("path")
            .attr("d", one_arc)

}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="donut" ref={(donut) => { this.donut = donut; }} />
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I see, you have an Array called ```secondOrderList```, but your pies variable looks like ```var pies = pie().value(d => {Math.abs(d.secondOrderImpact)});```. What is secondOrderImpact? Meaning, you use pies as your data, but I don't see that you've actually put the values from an Array into the data.

Comment: @mutantkeyboard `secondOrderList` is an array of dictionaries, and of its elements is `secondOrderImpact`. I'm trying to draw the donut based on the value of this element (`secondOrderImpact `). I thought `pie().value(d => {Math.abs(d.secondOrderImpact)});` will do the trick, d will be each array element of `secondOrderList ` and it will get the `secondOrderImpact ` of that element. Right?

Comment: Aha. Sorry. I haven't seen that last value of the dict.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem! 
One issue was here with the javascript syntax:
var pies = pie().value(d => Math.abs(d.secondOrderImpact));

I was using {} for the function and not returning any value (when using curly braces, you need to use return keyword!)

The other issue was I shouldn't have used the `append("path")` separately, here is the correct way:

```
group.selectAll(".seconOrderDonut")
    .data(pies)
    .enter()
        .append('g')
    .classed("seconOrderDonut", true)
    .append("path")
        .attr("d", one_arc)
        .style("fill", "red")
```